# How to prove PQ = QP using the product formula of polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $P$ and $Q$ be polynomials of $\mathbb{R}[X]$: $P(X) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} a_iX^i $ and $Q(X) = \sum_{i = 0}^{m} b_iX^i $

The product of two polynomials is defined as:

$$ PQ = \sum_{i = 0}^{n + m} ( \sum_{j = 0}^{i}a_ib_{i-j} )X^{i} $$

To prove that $ PQ = QP $, I need to change the index of the second sum: $ k = i-j $

I get $ \sum_{k = i}^{0} a_{k+j}b_k $

I don't know what I am missing to get $QP$. How can I proceed?

Comment: You started with the wrong formula. It should be $\sum_{j=0}^{i}a_{j}b_{i-j}$ instead of $i$ as subscript of the $a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite obvious if you write it in a symmetric way:
$$PQ = \sum_{i = 0}^{n + m}\biggl ( \sum_{k+\ell =i}a_k b_{\ell}\biggr )X^{i}= \sum_{i = 0}^{m+n}\biggl ( \sum_{\ell+k =i} b_{\ell}a_k\biggr )X^{i}=QP.$$

Comment: +1 very clear and simple

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation $ \sum_{\ell+k =i} $. At what value does it stop? What does mean that it starts with $ \ell+k =i $

Comment: It means you consider all pairs $(\ell,k)$  such that $\ell+k=i$ (of course \ell and $k$ are nonnegative). For instance, for $i=5$, you obtain the sum $\;b_0a_5+b_1a_4+b_2a_3+b_3a_2+b_4a_1+b_5a_0$.